# Android studio not able to pin the tabs

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a small querie regarding android studio layout. My preview and projects tabs are not showing. I found them in **View -> Tool windows**. but not able to pin them. They just come and go. not able to catch them :(

See image for reference :

[image]

As you can see in below image with red circle. that tabs are missing. that i am finding. tabs for Project, preview, Build anything not found.

[image]

Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: double click on any of the file(`tmp1.xml` or `item_test.xml`) in the above tabs

Comment: @vm345 nothing happened :/

Comment: goto View -> Tool Windows ->Project

Comment: @vm345 that way i got that pannel but once i close it. It will disappere i want them to pinned there.

Comment: @vm345 Yes my problem is solved tool buttons was not selected. Please post an answer i will select as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check whether **Toolbar,Tool Buttons,Navigation bar,Status Bar** are selected or not by clicking **View** option from the Menu

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow these setps to show the preview and project in

- Android Studio - View -> Tools Windows -> preview
- Once you click on preview you will able to see preview

Now to pin the preview

- Go to Window -> Active Tool Window -> Select pinned mode and Docked
  mode

Follow these same steps for Project

It will solve your problem

Comment: Nothing happens. when i close then they just disappears

Comment: ohk now pinned mode and docked mode  selected or not ?

Comment: Yes it is selected

Comment: i mean once they both selected you wont able to click those option.they both option will deactive...are you getting the same?

Comment: Yes they are disabled .

Comment: you not able to see logcat from view -tools windows>

Comment: I can see everything from view -tools windows. but nothing on my studio editor. why they are gone :( :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps to show the preview and project in

Android Studio - View -> Toolbar

Android Studio - View -> Tool buttons

Once you click on this Button you will able to see tool Buttons

[image]